16-bit ALU with multiplication - splitting 32-bit product for 16-bit output?
I'm having a hard time realising the multiplication process inside my 16-bit ALU. The obvious problem is that I have 2 16-bit inputs and one 16-bit output when the result is actually of 32-bits. I tried declaring an internal signal of 32 bits and then slicing it but it always outputs x"XXXX" in the bench test. My professor said that it would be better if I used a mux in order to select the bits of 32 bit ouput each time, selecting the 16msb when a and b are large numbers and the 16lsb when they are small. However, he isn't great at guiding me and I can't seem to be able to do it on my own. Can anyone tell me what's wrong with my current code and if what my professor says can be done?
library ieee; -- finished i think
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity alu is
    port(
    
    a       : in std_logic_vector (15 downto 0); -- opperand a
    b       : in std_logic_vector (15 downto 0); -- opperand b
    alu_sel : in std_logic_vector (3 downto 0); 
    sh : in std_logic_vector(2 downto 0);
    c  : out std_logic_vector (15 downto 0); -- output
    zer     : out std_logic); -- result equals 0
end entity;

architecture bhv of alu is

signal mul_sig : std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);

begin
    
    process(a,b,alu_sel) is
    begin
        
        if alu_sel = "0000" then
            c <= a and b;
        elsif alu_sel = "0001" then
            c <= a or b;
        elsif alu_sel = "0010" then
            c <= a xor b;
        elsif alu_sel = "0011" then
            c <=  std_logic_vector(unsigned(a) + unsigned(b)); 
        elsif alu_sel = "0100" then
            c <=  std_logic_vector(unsigned(a) - unsigned(b));
            if a = b then
                zer <= '1';
            else 
                zer <= '0';
            end if;
        elsif alu_sel = "0101" then -- logical left shift
            c <= std_logic_vector(shift_left(unsigned(a), to_integer(unsigned(sh))));
        elsif alu_sel = "0110" then -- logical right shift
            c <= std_logic_vector(shift_right(unsigned(a), to_integer(unsigned(sh))));
        elsif alu_sel = "0111" then 
            mul_sig <=  std_logic_vector(unsigned(a) * unsigned(b));
            c <= mul_sig(31 downto 16); -- this isn't working for some reason
        elsif alu_sel = "1000" then
            c <= not a;
        else 
            c <= (others =>'Z'); -- NULL?
        end if;
    end process;
end architecture;


Hello and welcome to SO. Your process is missing a couple of signals in the sensitivity list - specifically sh and mul_sig. Without mul_sig in the sensitivity list, C cannot be updated after mul_sig is assigned, hence it is always 'X'. I recommend using VHDL 2008 which allows process(all) to allow the compiler to determine the sensitivity list for itself from all the required signals in the process.

In addition, I recommend taking the tour and posting a MCVE. Your question title is not a question - and your problem statement is not very focussed.

@Tricky: Hrm, perhaps I shouldn't have approved this from the staging ground.  I thought there was enough text that was fairly close to asking a question, but I don't know VHDL so I didn't look at the code to see if it was reasonable.  I assumed an answer was going to look like "you actually need a 32-bit wide output, or another control input to select which half of the output you want, redoing the multiplication if you want both halves."  (Since selecting the half of the output containing the highest significant bit of the product doesn't make much sense, even if this was a float mantissa)

(Real CPUs that can only produce half of a multiply at once, like RISC-V, have separate instructions like mul and mulh which produce the low or high half respectively, regardless of the input values.  Classic MIPS puts the full result into special hi:lo registers where it can be read later, and many other ISAs have widening  mul that writes two GPRs, like x86 mul or ARM umull with the two ls indicating wide output in asm source syntax)

@Tricky While you have a point about the quality, your first comment is actually an answer. Please write it as such, this is not a forum.

Your process is missing a couple of signals in the sensitivity list - specifically sh and mul_sig. Without mul_sig in the sensitivity list, C cannot be updated after mul_sig is assigned, hence it is always 'X'. I recommend using VHDL 2008 which allows process(all) to allow the compiler to determine the sensitivity list for itself from all the required signals in the process.
